# Alternative to setting Same-Site Cookies to null in Laravel app when doing a POST request from a third-party website

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies, samesite

A little bit of context: I'm implementing a payment processor in a Laravel web application. After the user submits credit card information the payment processor makes a POST request to my application to inform me about the status of the transaction. Depending on that status, I'm redirecting the user to a page where I display a success or fail message.

The problem is that after that POST request the current session is lost and then when I'm redirecting the user to the transaction result page I don't have an active session anymore and the user needs to login.

After doing a little bit of research I found out that a possible solution is to set `'same_site' => null` in `session.php` and indeed it works, but this comes with some security risks which I'm not willing to take.

So I'm wondering if any of you ran into this issue before and what did you do to fix it, but without loosening application security.

Comment: But this is a scenario, that kinda requires that you "loosen application security" a bit - SameSite=Strict or Lax is _supposed to_ prevent this from working, but you _want_ it to work. Of course you can try and go a different way, like implement an extra step for the user to confirm - _don't_ pick the session up again directly on the page that they get redirected to, but put an additional "proceed" button there, that sends them somewhere else - _that_ would be a navigation _within_ your page again, so the browser should now send the original session cookie again as well.

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, but on the other hand you don't usually get to see that "proceed" button you mentioned. After a successful payment you usually get redirected back to the website to a thank you page where maybe you get a short summary of your order.

Comment: Yes, but those sites likely have their cookies not secured in terms of samesite then.

Comment: Yes, most likely...

Comment: @Cosmin any update or solution on it ?

Comment: Is there any other solution for this than setting the samesite to none?